# Reading CSV file with PHP and display the data in HTML/PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to create and read some csv files and display them using html but it's giving me some errors :/ , I followed a tutorial on youtube but it still gives me an error and I don't understand why

I used 3 columns in excel and i put some text but when I go to test it, it puts it in just one column

[Undefined array error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLBSO.png)

i tried to use var_dump function to check $data to see what i was getting through fgetcsv and i get this: "bool(false)"

I noticed that when saving an excel file, 3 or 4 options appear to save as csv

I chose "CSV(separated by commas)", i don't know if this could be the problem

this is the code i have: [Code1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mlj3Z.png),[Code2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdPFd.png)

[Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmCdw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because your delimiter in the file is a semi-colon.
But the delimiter set in "fgetcsv" is a comma.

You have to change that to a semi-colon.

Like this:

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE)
```